# LIST内に設定されたDTOの結合処理

Tags: java

LIST内に設定されているDTOをfor文でkeyに合わせて結合しようとしているのですが、上手いやりかたが思いつきません・・・

やりたいこと：
array1の中にそれぞれhoge1・hoge2・hoge3を入れ子に持たせたDTOを入れています。keyが一致するレコードを結合しarrayExに設定したいです。
keyが一致しないものは何もせずにarrayExに設定です。

最終的にarrayExにhoge1・hoge2・hoge3が設定されたものが1件。
hoge3が設定されただけのkeyが2のものが1件が理想です。

for文をいくつも使って再現はできたのですが、動作が遅いためダメでした・・・

どなたかご教授頂ければ幸いです。

以下ソースです。

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test1 test1 = new Test1();
        ArrayList<Test1> array1 = new ArrayList<Test1>();
        ArrayList<Test1> array2 = new ArrayList<Test1>();
        ArrayList<Test1> arrayEx = new ArrayList<Test1>();

        test1.setKey("1");
        test1.setHoge1("hoge1");
        test1.setHoge2(null);
        test1.setHoge3(null);
        array1.add(test1);
        test1 = new Test1();

        test1.setKey("1");
        test1.setHoge1(null);
        test1.setHoge2("hoge2");
        test1.setHoge3(null);
        array1.add(test1);
        test1 = new Test1();

        test1.setKey("1");
        test1.setHoge1(null);
        test1.setHoge2(null);
        test1.setHoge3("hoge3");
        array1.add(test1);
        test1 = new Test1();

        test1.setKey("2");
        test1.setHoge1(null);
        test1.setHoge2(null);
        test1.setHoge3("hoge3");
        array1.add(test1);
        test1 = new Test1();

        int count = array1.size();

        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < count-1; i++) {
            Test1 A = new Test1();
            Test1 B = new Test1();
            A = array1.get(i);
            B = array1.get(i+1);

            if(A.getKey().equals(B.getKey())) {

                if(!(A.getHoge1()==null)) {
                    B.setHoge1(A.getHoge1());
                }

                if(!(A.getHoge2()==null)) {
                    B.setHoge2(A.getHoge2());
                }

                if(!(A.getHoge3()==null)) {
                    B.setHoge3(A.getHoge2());
                }

                arrayEx.add(B);

            } else {
                arrayEx.add(A);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

以下現状です・・・色々試しているためかなり修正しています・・・

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test1 test1 = new Test1();
        List<Test1> array1 = new ArrayList<Test1>();
        ArrayList<Test1> array2 = new ArrayList<Test1>();
        List<Test1> arrayEx = new ArrayList<Test1>();

        test1.setKey("1");
        test1.setHoge1("hoge1");
        test1.setHoge2(null);
        test1.setHoge3(null);
        test1.setHoge4(null);
        array1.add(test1);
        test1 = new Test1();

        test1.setKey("1");
        test1.setHoge1(null);
        test1.setHoge2("hoge2");
        test1.setHoge3(null);
        test1.setHoge4(null);
        array1.add(test1);
        test1 = new Test1();

        test1.setKey("1");
        test1.setHoge1(null);
        test1.setHoge2(null);
        test1.setHoge3("hoge3");
        test1.setHoge4(null);
        array1.add(test1);
        test1 = new Test1();

        test1.setKey("1");
        test1.setHoge1(null);
        test1.setHoge2(null);
        test1.setHoge3(null);
        test1.setHoge4("hoge4");
        array1.add(test1);
        test1 = new Test1();


        test1.setKey("2");
        test1.setHoge1("hoge1");
        test1.setHoge2(null);
        test1.setHoge3(null);
        test1.setHoge4(null);
        array1.add(test1);
        test1 = new Test1();

        test1.setKey("2");
        test1.setHoge1(null);
        test1.setHoge2(null);
        test1.setHoge3("hoge3");
        test1.setHoge4(null);
        array1.add(test1);
        test1 = new Test1();

        int count = array1.size();

        int i = 0;
        Iterator<Test1> it = array1.iterator();



        //現在レコード
        Test1 A = new Test1();
        //次レコード
        Test1 B = new Test1();
        //一時退避
        Test1 C = new Test1();
        while(it.hasNext()) {

            B = array1.get(i+1);

            if(it.hasNext()) {

            A = it.next();
            }
            if(!(C.getKey()==null)) {
                if(B.getKey().equals(C.getKey())) {
                    if(!(B.getHoge1()==null)) {
                        C.setHoge1(B.getHoge1());
                    }

                    if(!(B.getHoge2()==null)) {
                        C.setHoge2(B.getHoge2());
                    }

                    if(!(B.getHoge3()==null)) {
                        C.setHoge3(B.getHoge3());
                    }
                    if(!(Objects.equals(B.getHoge4(), null))) {
                        C.setHoge4(B.getHoge4());
                    }
                    i = i + 1;
                }else {
                    arrayEx.add(C);
                    C = new Test1();
                    i = i + 1;
                }



            } 

            if(C.getKey()==null) {
                if(A.getKey().equals(B.getKey())) {

                    if(!(A.getHoge1()==null)) {
                        C.setHoge1(A.getHoge1());
                    }else if(!(B.getHoge1()==null)) {
                        C.setHoge1(B.getHoge1());
                    }

                    if(!(A.getHoge2()==null)) {
                        C.setHoge2(A.getHoge2());
                    }else if(!(B.getHoge2()==null)) {
                        C.setHoge2(B.getHoge2());
                    }

                    if(!(A.getHoge3()==null)) {
                        C.setHoge3(A.getHoge3());
                    }else if(!(B.getHoge3()==null)) {
                        C.setHoge3(B.getHoge3());
                    }

                    if(!(A.getHoge4()==null)) {
                        C.setHoge4(A.getHoge4());
                    }else if(!(B.getHoge4()==null)) {
                        C.setHoge4(B.getHoge4());
                    }

                    C.setKey(A.getKey());

                    i = i + 1;

                } else {
                    arrayEx.add(B);
                    i = i + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: はじめまして、ご質問の内容ですが。前半部分はテストデータということでいいでしょうか? `キー`が一致するとありますが、キーは`何と`一致するのでしょうか? ソースコードを見ると、インデックスが直後のものと比較されているようですが、リストの最後にあるものは何と比較すればよいのでしょうか?

Comment: 申し訳ありません言葉足らずでした。前半部分はテストデータになります。キーについては「test1.setKey("1");」部分のものがキーとなっています。リストの最後の考慮が漏れていました・・・最後のレコードについても同様に直前のレコードとキーが一致すれば結合をさせたいです。今思いつくものとしては別のインスタンスを作成（Test1 C = new Test1();など）し、一旦退避させておくといった方針になるのでしょうか・・・現在の状況を追記するのでよろしければご確認のほど宜しくお願い致します。初心者なもので見当違いなことを言っているかもしれません。宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

同じキーを持つ複数のデータを集約したり集計したりする場合、一般的には Map 型を使うことになるかと思います。

```
import java.util.*;

class Test1{
    private String key;
    private String hoge1;
    private String hoge2;
    private String hoge3;

    public void setKey(String newKey){
        this.key = newKey;
    }
    public void setHoge1(String newHoge1){
        this.hoge1 = newHoge1;
    }
    public void setHoge2(String newHoge2){
        this.hoge2 = newHoge2;
    }
    public void setHoge3(String newHoge3){
        this.hoge3 = newHoge3;
    }
    public String getKey(){
        return this.key;
    }
    public String getHoge1(){
        return this.hoge1;
    }
    public String getHoge2(){
        return this.hoge2;
    }
    public String getHoge3(){
        return this.hoge3;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return String.format("{key => %s, hoge1 => %s, hoge2 => %s, hoge3 => %s", getKey(), getHoge1(), getHoge2(), getHoge3());
    }
}

public class Test {
    static ArrayList<Test1> createExampleData(){
        ArrayList<Test1> exampleData = new ArrayList<Test1>();
        Test1 test1;

        test1 = new Test1();
        test1.setKey("1");
        test1.setHoge1("1-hoge1");
        test1.setHoge2(null);
        test1.setHoge3(null);
        exampleData.add(test1);

        test1 = new Test1();
        test1.setKey("1");
        test1.setHoge1(null);
        test1.setHoge2("1-hoge2");
        test1.setHoge3(null);
        exampleData.add(test1);

        test1 = new Test1();
        test1.setKey("1");
        test1.setHoge1(null);
        test1.setHoge2(null);
        test1.setHoge3("1-hoge3");
        exampleData.add(test1);

        test1 = new Test1();
        test1.setKey("2");
        test1.setHoge1(null);
        test1.setHoge2(null);
        test1.setHoge3("2-hoge3");
        exampleData.add(test1);

        return exampleData;
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Test1> array1 = createExampleData();
        ArrayList<Test1> arrayEx = new ArrayList<Test1>();
        TreeMap<String, Test1> tmpTable = new TreeMap<String, Test1>();
        System.out.println("Input array");

        for(Test1 test1 : array1) {
            System.out.println(test1);
            String key = test1.getKey();
            if(tmpTable.containsKey(key)){
                // すでに出現済みのキーの場合 tmpTable から取り出し、そこに結合する
                Test1 data = tmpTable.get(key);
                if(test1.getHoge1() != null) {
                    data.setHoge1(test1.getHoge1());
                }

                if(test1.getHoge2() != null) {
                    data.setHoge2(test1.getHoge2());
                }

                if(test1.getHoge3() != null) {
                    data.setHoge3(test1.getHoge3());
                }
            }
            else{
                // 初出のキーの場合 tmpTable に格納する
                tmpTable.put(key, test1);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Output array");
        arrayEx.addAll(tmpTable.values());
        for(Test1 test1 : arrayEx) {
            System.out.println(test1);
        }
    }
}
```

以下、実行結果。

```
Input array
{ key => 1, hoge1 => 1-hoge1, hoge2 => null, hoge3 => null }
{ key => 1, hoge1 => null, hoge2 => 1-hoge2, hoge3 => null }
{ key => 1, hoge1 => null, hoge2 => null, hoge3 => 1-hoge3 }
{ key => 2, hoge1 => null, hoge2 => null, hoge3 => 2-hoge3 }
Output array
{ key => 1, hoge1 => 1-hoge1, hoge2 => 1-hoge2, hoge3 => 1-hoge3 }
{ key => 2, hoge1 => null, hoge2 => null, hoge3 => 2-hoge3 }
```

Answer (score 0):

リストに入っているオブジェクトを `key` ごとに分類するのには Stream API の `groupingBy` による `collect` が利用できます:

```java
Map<String, List<Test1>> group = array1.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Test1::getKey));
```

これで `key` ごとに分類された `Test1` オブジェクトのリストが手に入りましたので、このリスト内の全オブジェクトを"結合"すれば所望の結果が得られます。

"結合"は、同じく Stream API の `reduce` が利用できます:

```java
for (List<Test1> list : group.values()) {
    // listの中身はすべて同じkeyでグルーピングされているので
    // 全てを順繰りに結合
    Optional<Test1> merged = list.stream().reduce((t1, t2) -> {
        String t1Hoge1 = t1.getHoge1();
        if (t1Hoge1 != null) {
            t2.setHoge1(t1Hoge1);
        }
        String t1Hoge2 = t1.getHoge2();
        if (t1Hoge2 != null) {
            t2.setHoge2(t1Hoge2);
        }
        String t1Hoge3 = t1.getHoge3();
        if (t1Hoge3 != null) {
            t2.setHoge3(t1Hoge3);
        }
        return t2;
    });

    // 結合結果を格納
    merged.ifPresent(arrayEx::add);
}
```

なお、この "結合" は、DTOを扱う上でよく行う処理であり、このような処理を行うためのライブラリも複数開発されています。
これらのライブラリの(主たる)目的は、いわゆるボイラープレートコードの削減です。

次のページでそのうちのいくつかを見ることができます:

- [Performance of Java Mapping Frameworks](https://www.baeldung.com/java-performance-mapping-frameworks) - Baeldung

参考として、MapStructを利用した場合の実装サンプルをリンクします:

- https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so63384